# animations on a jquery mobile phonegap app

Tags: flash, jquery-mobile, animation, cordova, spritely

I have a client that insist on having animations on their JQM/PhoneGap app I am developing. The original animation was Flash (.swf) and videos. I am taking a training manual that was a made in the a basic website and using JQM and PhoneGapping it into an app. No problem with that part. Putting the current animations and video is where I am lost. I looked into Spritely.net but it warns of over using it in an app. Some chapters have up to 10 different animations/videos. The kicker is this app has to work offline.

Thanks for responding.

Griff

Comment: Flash animations on mobile devices? Bad idea. Your client can change its items or just want them to be integrated as is?

Comment: What is your actual question?  Are you looking for advice or a framework to use?  Show some code of what needs to be animated and what you've tried.  be more specific on what should happen.   As it stands, your question is too broad.